# JRuby fresh install on Windows 10 - Could not find or load main class org.jruby.Main

Tags: java, windows, jruby

> `jruby -v` is returning `Error: Could not find or load main class org.jruby.Main`

I downloaded *jruby-dist-9.1.12.0-src.zip* from the JRuby website and then extracted its contents into **C:\jruby-9.1.12.0**.

Then I added its **bin** folder to the "path" variable using `setx path "%path%;C:\jruby-9.1.12.0\bin"`. The command `echo %PATH%` returns `C:\jruby-9.1.12.0\bin` as one of the entries.

I have even set a couple environment variables. `set | findstr JRUBY_HOME` returns `JRUBY_HOME=C:\jruby-9.1.12.0`, and `set | findstr JAVA_HOME` returns `JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jre8`.

What am I missing? Did I download the wrong JRuby?

Comment: its not clear what you're running: `java` doesn't know anything about JRuby.
you could just run `jruby -v` to verify it works

Comment: Sorry @kares! That typo materially changed the question! It's `jruby -v` that returns the error. I've edited the question to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

> **TLDR** use the bin download; *NOT* the src download.

I got it to work by removing the contents in **C:\jruby-9.1.12.0** (which came from *jruby-dist-9.1.12.0-src.zip*). Then I downloaded *jruby-bin-9.1.12.0.zip* and extracted its contents into **C:\jruby-9.1.12.0**.